# Property declaration error in Objective-C++

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, macros, objective-c++

I have "Constants.h" header file, that contains macros like:

```
#define IS_IOS_SIMULATOR TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define IS_IOS (TARGET_OS_IOS || IS_IOS_SIMULATOR)
#define IS_MAC (TARGET_OS_MAC)
#if IS_IOS
#define xColor UIColor
#elif IS_MAC
#define xColor NSColor
#endif
```

It allows me to use same code for both iOS and macOS apps. And my entire code is in Objective-C++, so I put type casts everywhere. Problems appear normally in header files, when it comes to properties declarations like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) xColor *colorProp;
```

XCode keeps throwing exceptions like:

> Unknown type name 'xColor', did you mean ...?

Even if "Constants.h" file is imported and required libraries are connected. 
Is there a way to disable those exceptions and finally compile my code?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `*` somewhere there, but I don't think that's your fundamental problem

Comment: Oh, fixed that. Just was typing a question in a hurry. Its just an example.

Comment: Thanks for response anyway!

Comment: One approach would be to use Product->Perform action->Preprocess on your source file that contains the property.  It would let you see where your constants header was being imported and the effect on your declaration (if any).

Comment: Are you sure that one or the other definition is actually active within the header where the property is? You can use #error or #warning pragmas to check

Comment: I have tried #error right now and it says that macro is not defined. It seems like the issue is within contents of Constants file

Comment: I have update Constants file content in the question. Maybe you can see if there is a mistake in the way those #define statements are written?

Comment: The value (not the definition) of the macros depends on the value of other macros not in your Q. However, going back to the source of the error with depending macros is a pain. Check, whether `TARGET_OS_MAC` pp. exist at compile time (with `#if` and `ifdef` + `#error`), if not, go back to their definition …

Comment: I have included TargetConditionals.h, that contains definitions. And it seems, that when I try to launch the app in simulator it thinks, that we have macOS as a target. Is there another analog to TARGET_OS_MAC ?

Answer (score 0):

When using Macro to detect device you are currently running on, make sure that you define them in following way:

```
#define IS_IOS_SIMULATOR TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define IS_IOS (TARGET_OS_IOS || IS_IOS_SIMULATOR)
#define IS_MAC (TARGET_OS_MAC && !IS_IOS_SIMULATOR)
```

Thanks to Phillip Mills  and Amin Negm-Awad for assistance!